# Given an array of +ve integers, Find the number which occurs odd number of times in O(n) time & constant space.

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given an array of positive integers. All numbers occur even number of times except one number which occurs odd number of times. Find the number in O(n) time & constant space.

```
int getOddOccurrence ( int ar[]){
    int i;
    int res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ar.size; i++)
        res = res ^ ar[i];
    return res;
}

/* Diver function to test above function */
PSVM() {
    int ar[] = {2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2};
    SOP(getOddOccurrence(ar));
}
```

Approach 1: By X-OR ing all the elements in an array

I am trying to x-or all the elements. Is that the
correct approach? Above is the code using X-OR

Approach 2: By using HashMap
If I use hashmap , the space complexity would be O(n). Which is not good.

Which approach should I use?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly a clear enough specification here. What happens if more than one number occurs an odd number of times, for example? And the idea of doing this in constant *time* is mad...

Comment: The space complexity is O(log) in the average case since you don't need to store dupes in the hashmap.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The question has been corrected to constant space and O(N) time. I'm not sure that makes more sense, unless space is pushed to O(MAX_INT).

Comment: Is it "find the number" or "find the numbers" or "find the first number" or "find any number from the array"?

Comment: See here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-occurring-odd-number-of-times/ Is this where you try to copy from? These numbers are very small. Maybe there's an additional requirement that they are in the range [0, 7] or [0, 15].

Comment: OK, this solution assumes there's only one such number in the array (with odd count of occurrences). Yes, then it works, then it's OK (and is pretty obvious btw).

Comment: `Maybe there's an additional requirement that they are in the range [0, 7] or [0, 15].` No, there's no need for such a requirement.

Comment: @JonSkeet, It's not *completely* mad.  A bit-string with a bit for each 32B integer fits in 512MB which is addressable :)  The problem is that the time to scan that bit-string is O(|ℤ|) for your approximation of ℤ, so unless you know that you're running on an OS that let's you tell whether a page of memory is all zero in constant time without paging it in, the time to initialize or scan that bit-string is going to exceed the time it'd take to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

This problem assumes there is only one number which occurs odd number of
times in the array. If you have more such numbers - say K of them: `a1, a2, ... aK`,
then at the end of the loop, in `res` you will get this value.

`res == a1 ^ a2 ^ ... ^ aK`

From that value you cannot infer/extract all K unknown numbers `a1, a2, ... aK`.

Buf ... you see, if K=1 (i.e. if you have exactly one number occurring
odd number of times), at the end you will get in `res` just that number.

Use the first approach as long as you understand why it works.

Also, in the second approach the space is not `O(n)` but `O(s)`,
where `s` is the count of distinct values in your array. And as you
have only 1 number occurring odd number of times we can say for sure
that `2*s + 1 <= n` i.e. `s <= (n-1)/2`. So the space complexity
is `O((n-1)/2)` in the second approach. You achieve it when your array
looks like this: `s` numbers occurring twice, and `1` number occurring once.